# Group By Popular keynames

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

Lets say have a records in the system, below are a few:

1. How to delete a record?
2. delete a record from system
3. user wants to delete products
4. delete multiple user accounts

I want to search for the most populate types of records. In the above records the word "delete" comes up alot. I would like to write a query that will group the most popular records.

I have tried:

```
SELECT NAME, COUNT(*)
FROM REQUESTS
GROUP BY NAME
```

I would like a column on the end called, "Most Popular Key Word"

Comment: I'm not quite sure, what you mean by records, requests and key words. Is it that you have a column `name` in your `requests` table where the entries are these in the list? And if yes, do you want a result like delete => 4, record => 2, ... so basically a word count?

Answer (score 0):

This finds you the most popular keyword found in each field:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Name VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES ('How to delete a record?')
    , ('delete a record from system')
    , ('user wants to delete products')
    , ('delete multiple user accounts');

SELECT TOP (1)d.column1 AS Keywords, COUNT(*) AS KeywordCount
FROM @T AS T
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetTableFromList(T.Name, ' ') AS D
GROUP BY D.column1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

`dbo.GetTableFromList()` is a split-string function (it splits string into rows using given delimiter). A very detailed article explaining these can be found  [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings). In this case function splits each `Name` cell by space and generates a row for each word.

It would be great to remove all non alphanumeric characters to have consistent results using [CLR RegExReplace](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/) function using this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM @T AS T
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetTableFromList(dbo.RegExReplace(T.Name, '[^A-Za-z0-9 ]', ' '), ' ') AS D;
```

So as the first step you can see what's generated using this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM @T AS T
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetTableFromList(T.Name, ' ') AS D;

ID  Name                            column1
-------------------------------------------
1   How to delete a record?         How
1   How to delete a record?         to
1   How to delete a record?         delete
1   How to delete a record?         a
1   How to delete a record?         record?
2   delete a record from system     delete
2   delete a record from system     a
2   delete a record from system     record
2   delete a record from system     from
2   delete a record from system     system
3   user wants to delete products   user
3   user wants to delete products   wants
3   user wants to delete products   to
3   user wants to delete products   delete
3   user wants to delete products   products
4   delete multiple user accounts   delete
4   delete multiple user accounts   multiple
4   delete multiple user accounts   user
4   delete multiple user accounts   accounts
```

What's done next is grouping by each generated keyword and sorting by its count, returning the most popular one as the first one (using `TOP (1)` statement).

```
Keywords    KeywordCount
------------------------
delete      4
a           2
to          2
user        2
wants       1
accounts    1
from        1
How         1
multiple    1
products    1
record      1
record?     1
system      1
```

If you're going to use CLR RegExReplace, then it's going to return you a cleaner list of keywords (see `record` and `record?` are now same):

```
SELECT d.column1 AS Keywords, COUNT(*) AS KeywordCount
FROM @T AS T
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetTableFromList(dbo.RegExReplace(T.Name, '[^A-Za-z0-9 ]', ' '), ' ') AS D
GROUP BY D.column1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;

Keywords    KeywordCount
------------------------
delete      4
a           2
record      2
to          2
user        2
wants       1
system      1
accounts    1
from        1
How         1
multiple    1
products    1
```

On top of that. There could a be a lot of so called stopwords (noisewords). Possible way to remove these would be using [sys.fulltext_stopwords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280608.aspx) with `language_id = 1033` (English) using this code:

```
SELECT d.column1 AS Keywords, COUNT(*) AS KeywordCount
FROM @T AS T
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetTableFromList(dbo.RegExReplace(T.Name, '[^A-Za-z0-9 ]', ' '), ' ') AS D
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM sys.fulltext_stopwords AS FS
        WHERE FS.stopword = CAST(d.column1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
            AND FS.language_id = 1033
        )
GROUP BY D.column1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

**RESULT**

```
Keywords    KeywordCount
------------------------
delete      4
record      2
user        2
wants       1
accounts    1
system      1
multiple    1
products    1
```

**ADDITIONAL UPDATE**

This query also tries to look at basic word forms, for instance *records* would be recognized as *record*.

Please test:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Name VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES ('How to delete a record?')
    , ('delete a record from system')
    , ('user wants to delete products')
    , ('delete multiple user accounts')
    , ('how does someone delete multiple records');

SELECT S.display_term AS Keywords, COUNT(*) AS KeywordCount
FROM @T AS T
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CAST(D.column1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    FROM dbo.GetTableFromList(dbo.RegExReplace(T.Name, '[^A-Za-z0-9 ]', ' '), ' ') AS D
    ) AS D(Phrase)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) S.display_term
    FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('FORMSOF(FREETEXT, "' + D.Phrase + '")', 1033, 0, 0) AS S
    WHERE S.source_term = D.Phrase
    ORDER BY S.keyword
    ) AS S
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM sys.fulltext_stopwords AS FS
        WHERE FS.stopword = D.Phrase
            AND FS.language_id = 1033
        )
GROUP BY S.display_term
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a solution for small table sizes, when the both table sizes increase the performance will be decreasing fast

As you can understand, I used a keyword table and populated it manually. This can avoid using noisy words like "an", "and", etc which can be considered as a result of splitting

```
/*
Create Table Requests (id int identity(1,1), Request nvarchar(max))
insert into Requests select 'How to delete a record?'
insert into Requests select 'delete a record from system'
insert into Requests select 'user wants to delete products'
insert into Requests select 'delete multiple user accounts'
*/
--Create Table Keywords (keyword nvarchar(100))
--insert into Keywords values ('delete'),('user'),('how'),('account'),('system'),('product')
select k.keyword, count(k.keyword) as cnt
from Requests r
cross apply Keywords k 
where r.Request like ('%' + k.keyword + '%')
group by k.keyword
```

A better way of above solution can be using [SQL Server full-text search](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/SQL-Server-Full-Text-Search-Indexing.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use **SQL Server Semantic Search** for this task, it will provide you the most frequently used key phrases or keywords in your table.

Please refer to **[SQL Server semantic search tutorial](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2014/fulltext-index-semantic-search-in-sql-server-2014.aspx)** to enable full-text search and semantic search on SQL Server, and also to create full-text index and query text data for significant key phrases using SQL Semantic Search function **SemanticKeyPhraseTable**

I also placed the Select query you can use for this requirement,

```
;WITH tbl as (
    SELECT * FROM SemanticKeyPhraseTable(Requests, Request)
    INNER JOIN Requests ON document_key = id
)
SELECT TOP 3 keyphrase, COUNT(*)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY keyphrase
ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc
```

I strongly suggest you to integrate full-text indexes to your database solution and configure semantic search for text analyzing tasks